# TrueNAS Plex plugin DNS Error

Tags: dns, dhcp, plex, truenas

I'm fairly new to TrueNAS and have just setup a server with it installed. I want to install plex using the plugin. when I install plex with DHCP and NAT unchecked I use the ipv4 interface as vnet0 and then I added a static IP to the network page in TrueNAS and then used that along with the netmask of 32.

I then get this error:

> Error: plex had a failure Exception: RuntimeError Message: Stopped plex due to VNET failure Partial plugin destroyed

If i check NAT i get no error but the page is unresponsive

With DHCP checked i get the error:

> Error: plex had a failure Exception: RuntimeError Message: + Acquiring DHCP address: FAILED, address received: ERROR, check jail logs Stopped plex due to DHCP failure Partial plugin destroyed

I spent the entire day trying to fix this by adding a DNS and configuring more internet options but that doesn't work. I then looked at multiple posts and they didn't help at all.